# ¿Un EJB remoto puede utilizar Clases (que no son EJBs) para ser utilizadas por un cliente remoto?

Tags: java-ee, ejb, jdbc, wildfly

Situación:

Tengo un EJB Project. Tiene un modelo de Clases que contiene la lógica de negocio y conexión a Base de Datos (las clases utilizan JDBC). Dentro del mismo proyecto, estas clases son utilizadas por EJBs remotos. ¿Por qué? Porque estos EJBs serán utilizados por un cliente remoto, mediante sus Interfaces de acceso remoto.

El proyecto hace el deploy en WildFly correctamente.
Desde el EJB Project se persiste en la BBDD correctamente.

Cliente:

Es un Java Project. El problema aparece cuando el cliente quiere servirse de los EJBs.

Tengo todo bien configurado: el jndi.properties, el BuildPath, las librerías de WildFLy, etc. La duda y el error, creo, viene de la mano de especificaciones de los EJBs que no puedo encontrar por ningún lado.

La duda es: **¿un EJB puede utilizar clases que conecten a la BBDD mediante JDBC (PreparedStatement, ResultSet, etc.), o debo sí o sí utilizar JPA?**

Si es posible que los EJBs puedan utilizarlas, no comprendo por qué el cliente remoto no puede utilizar las funcionalidades.

Espero haber sido claro. No adjunto código porque todo el código de la lógica está testeado y funciona bien. La duda puntual es la resaltada en negrita.

Answer (score 0):

Si es un EJB debería estar anotado por lo menos con @Stateless o @Stateful, lo que significa que es EJB. Ahora estos EJBs son gestionados por Wildfly dentro un contenedor, una de estas gestiones son las transacciones.

Ahora tienes dos opciones dentro un EJB para manejar transacciones:

- Gestionado por Bean: "@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)", lo que significa que la conexión la sacas del contenedor mediante EntityManager (con JPA).
- Gestionando Manejado por contendor: 
  "@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)", la conexión de la creas mediante UserTransaction usando luego JDBC (sin JPA).

En los dos casos las conexiones las saca de un DataSource en tu configuracion de standalone.xml.

Ahora también puedes crear conexiones dentro el EJB manualmente: desde crear el DataSource y todo el ciclo hasta realizar una consulta y cerrar la conexión. Todos estaría bajo tu control y no de Wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas

La duda es: ¿un EJB puede utilizar clases que conecten a la BBDD mediante JDBC (PreparedStatement, ResultSet, etc.), o debo sí o sí utilizar JPA?

Respuesta:Si un EJB puedo usar una clase que este conecte con una db, la cual este este configurado para JPA como para JDBC.La forma correcta tendria que ser llamar desde el cliente a la clase de logica la cual hace uso de la capa de acceso a datos. Via @Remote con una interfaz declarada en la capa de logica (capa de negocio) misma tiene que implementar dicha interfaz.

El cliente tiene via JNDI con:

```
private static final String JNDI_EJB_REMOTE= "PROYECTO_NAME/CLASE_EJB/REMOTE_OR_EJBNAME";
```

MiBeanRemoteInterface bean = (MiBeanRemoteInterface) context.lookup(JNDI_EJB_REMOTE);

Te dejo una declaracion de context de ejemplo para un cliente remoto y un link para informacion adicional:

context jboos:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
    Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

link:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Remote+JNDI+Reference?_sscc=t